# Javascript force recalculate value of object property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to re-use an "object", however, one of the object's properties values should be recalculated every time the object is accessed.

In my code I have a library which can basically make a list of card views from a data url. This list of card views is added to a page. There are two types of lists: Active Buildings list and Archived Buildings list. Switching between these two lists is done by pressing a button, which triggers the "rerender" function of the repeater shown below.

Archived Buildings should not be clickable. I pass along some configuration options to my library where I handle the relevant parts. However, because of the way I invoke the card view library, the value of the `enableClick` configuration option is always set to what the state was like at the load of the page.

Example of how the code looks:

```
$(function () {
    var buildingsContainer = $('#buildings');
    buildingsContainer.repeater({
        url: function () {
            var activeFilter = buildingFilter.find('.btn-primary').data('status');
            return '/Building/All?status=' + activeFilter;
        },
        renderItem: cardTemplates(buildingsContainer).building({
            activateBuildingUrl: '@(Url.Action("ActivateBuilding", "Building"))/{Id}',
            editUrl: '@(Url.Action("Edit", "Building"))/{Id}',
            deleteBuildingUrl: '@(Url.Action("SoftDeleteBuilding", "Building"))/{Id}',
            enableClick: getActiveFilter() === 'Active'
        })
    })
});

function getActiveFilter() {
    var buildingFilter = $('#buildingFilter');
    return buildingFilter.find('.btn-primary').data('status');
}
```

No matter what the currently pressed button is, `enableClick` is always set to what it was when the page opened.

**To better demonstrate my problem, I have created a JSFiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/e3xnbxov/

In this JSFiddle, you see I have a `options` object with a `value` property. In the button's click listeners I print this value. However, it always remains on `Active`, even though I switch between `Active` and `Archived`. How can I make it so the value of the property is recalculated?

Comment: you have to update the option in the click (this for the fiddle) https://jsfiddle.net/amjwzq2p/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have 2 options here.

1) Set the property as a function, and evaluate it:

```
$(function() {
    var options = {
        value: ()=>$('#container').find('.btn-primary').data('status')
    };
    var container = $('#container');
    container.find('.btn').click(function() {
        container.find('.btn').removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');
        $(this).addClass('btn-primary');
        console.log(options.value());
    });
});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mw8kuq6L/

2) Just use "this" to directly access the data value you want to check:

```
$(function() {
    var container = $('#container');
    container.find('.btn').click(function() {
        container.find('.btn').removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');
        $(this).addClass('btn-primary');
        console.log($(this).data('status'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I went with the first option: turning it into a function. This solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the object (`options`) is created once, and the property is set once.

At the moment that the creation (and property setting) occurs, the 'active' button matches the jQuery selector (`$('#container').find('.btn-primary')`).

Javascript, like many languages, uses references.  When you set the object's property, it received a reference to the *result* of the jQuery selector, not the *selector* (as a method) itself.

You could change it to behave more as you're expecting by creating a method on your object:

```
$(function() {
    var options = {
        value: function () {
         return $('#container').find('.btn-primary').data('status')
      }
    };
    var container = $('#container');
    container.find('.btn').click(function() {
        container.find('.btn').removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');
        $(this).addClass('btn-primary');
        console.log(options.value());
    });
});
```

Thus your `options` object now has a callable method which dynamically returns what you were expecting.

Otherwise I'd *update* the property when the selected button changes:

```
$(function() {
    var options = {
        value: $('#container').find('.btn-primary').data('status')
    };
    var container = $('#container');
    container.find('.btn').click(function() {
        container.find('.btn').removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');
        $(this).addClass('btn-primary');
    options.value = $('#container').find('.btn-primary').data('status');
        console.log(options.value);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

*This is just meant to be an addition to lpg's answer.*

Another way would be to use a getter function which behaves like lpg's `value` function but can be used like a normal property:

```js
$(function() {
  var options = {
    // define a getter for the property 'value'
    get value () {
      return $('#container').find('.btn-primary').data('status');
    }
  };
  var container = $('#container');
  container.find('.btn').click(function() {
    container.find('.btn').removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');
    $(this).addClass('btn-primary');
    console.log(options.value); // use the property for the property 'value'
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-status="Active">Active</button>
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-status="Archived">Archived</button>
</div>
```